# Sphinx can't cope with function assignment inside class definition

Tags: python, class, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm using Sphinx together with autodoc and numpydoc extensions to generate a documentation of a pretty complex package. I run into one problem inside that auto-generation:

Let's say I have a package with two modules `calculator.py` and `math.py`.

Inside the `calculator.py`, I have definded a class, which assigns a function from the `math.py` module as a standard variable:

```
class Calculation(object):
    def some_calculation(some_variable,calculate=math.multiplication)
```

In my sphinx documentation, I include this class using the autoclass extension similar to

```
.. autoclass:: some_package.calculator.Calculation
    :members:
```

In my documentation, the function now shows up as a pointer, rather than the name:

```
some_calculation(some_variable,calculate=<function multiplication at 0x2b8882ef7f50>)
```

Is this something, I can change in the Sphinx configuration, so that my output looks like:

```
some_calculation(some_variable,calculate=math.multiplication)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a docstring to `some_calculation` where the first line is the signature that you want:

```
class Calculation(object):
    def some_calculation(self, some_variable, calculate=math.multiplication):
        """some_calculation(some_variable, calculate=math.multiplication)

           More text...
        """
        ...
```

Reference: http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_docstring_signature